# ZAP Error [java.net.SocketException]: Connection reset

Tags: zap

I launch our application for test with chrome browser using the manual explore option from zap and getting the below error. I save the SSL certificate from ZAP and imported to chrome browser, still getting the below error. Help me on resolving this?

```
ZAP Error [java.net.SocketException]: Connection reset


Stack Trace:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:860)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.flushRequestOutputStream(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1565)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2278)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1160)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:470)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:207)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.executeMethod(HttpSender.java:430)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.runMethod(HttpSender.java:672)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:627)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAuthenticated(HttpSender.java:602)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAuthenticated(HttpSender.java:585)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(HttpSender.java:490)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(HttpSender.java:460)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.processHttp(ProxyThread.java:562)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.run(ProxyThread.java:319)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you are not launching Chrome from ZAP?
That way you dont have to set up the certificate and ZAP automatically sets it up correctly.

Comment: I am launching Chrome from Zap only when chrome launches and opens the application, I am getting above socket connection error.

Comment: Do you get that error with all apps or just specific ones?

Comment: i got for one of our internal apps. For outside apps we have zscaler(security app for our company) installed which blocked to use.

Comment: So its just one specific app? If so then do you know if theres anything different about this app? Can you access it using another tool like curl?
It might be worth having a look at this thread on the ZAP User Group as well: https://groups.google.com/g/zaproxy-users/c/OuGcKmxMO0I

Comment: I have two apps for testing and one website is working if i remove https and make it http. Another application we have is always re-direct to https and hence getting above error. What need to do? the above solution didn't use for me.

Comment: Can you access it using another tool like curl?

Comment: I think some certificate installation issue or something. This is working fine in firefox. Setup the certificate for firefox as per the attached article. https://medium.com/@hiregovindawagle/owasp-zap-how-to-intercept-https-sites-f41b2247785c. Where as in chrome also installed the certificate in Trusted Certificates still getting the same issue

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but this isn't exactly a solution. Its a comment.